# HttpContext required for LogEntries?

Tags: appharbor

I'm using LogEntries as an add-on on AppHarbor. While everything works fine when logging via the controllers, I can't get any log from a worker running on a separate thread.
Is it LogEntries dependent on an HttpContext?

Comment: LogEntries shouldn't be dependent on any ASP.NET specific technology. Are you using the [NLog or the log4net](https://logentries.com/doc/appharbor/) adapter?

Comment: There's really no reason it shouldn't work, have you verified that the backgroundworker is running?